# How to remove special characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, decode

I am facing an issue in below code due to special characters(�) in description.Because of these special character i am getting an error.

**Error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 821: ordinal not in range(128)
Please help me to remove this error.**

Data in text form and data in html form given below respectively

Link: http://m.cellularoutfitter.com/p-85870-anycom-solar-bluetooth-car-kit_c.html (having descripton at the end of page)

I have tried various methods and encodings but failed.

First i get the complete src of link then By using x path I get the description in a variable.
i can not post the complete code because of some reasons. Sorry

Python code:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, encoding="utf-8")
tree = etree.HTML(popup_html, parser)
    description = tree.xpath("//span[@itemprop='description' and not(src)] ")

log.debug(str(description[0]))
for desc in description:
    log.debug(etree.tostring(desc,encoding='UTF-8'))
    if etree.tostring(desc,encoding='UTF-8').find("IFRAME") < 0:
        reply_dict['product_desc'] = reply_dict['product_desc'] + etree.tostring(desc,encoding='UTF-8')
        reply_dict['product_desc'] = reply_dict['product_desc'].replace("&#13;\n", "").replace("\n", "<br/>").replace("img","").replace('< src="/productPics/altImgs/decal-skin-pdp-2.jpg"/>',"")
        reply_dict['product_desc'] = reply_dict['product_desc'].replace("\xef\xbf\xbd","'")
        reply_dict['product_desc'] = reply_dict['product_desc'].replace("\x92","'")
        reply_dict['product_desc'] = "<br />".join(reply_dict['product_desc'].split("\n")).replace("     ", "&nbsp;").encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="centerContain">
            Convenient Bluetooth car kit easily mounts to vehicle windshield and features high-performance solar panel capable of converting UV rays into Bluetooth battery power. What's included: ANYCOM Solar Bluetooth Car Kit, window mount, suction cups, 12/24V vehicle power adapter w/USB cable, 3M adhesive tape, user guide.
            <ul>
                <li>Solar panel recharges battery, providing 30 minutes of talk time for every 3 hours of sun light</li><li>Features Digital Signal Processing (DSP) technology, including compression and echo cancellation</li><li>Easily pairs with compatible devices</li><li>Bluetooth: v2.0</li><li>Talk Time: 15 hours</li><li>Standby Time: 25 days</li><li>Operating Range: 33 ft. (10 meters)</li><li>Size: 3.59� (H) x 1.98� (W) x 0.52� (D)</li><li>Weight: 2.11 oz.</li><li>Warranty: ANYCOM limited worldwide 2-year warranty</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

In text Form:

Convenient Bluetooth car kit easily mounts to vehicle windshield and features high-performance solar panel capable of converting UV rays into Bluetooth battery power. What's included: ANYCOM Solar Bluetooth Car Kit, window mount, suction cups, 12/24V vehicle power adapter w/USB cable, 3M adhesive tape, user guide.
Solar panel recharges battery, providing 30 minutes of talk time for every 3 hours of sun light
Features Digital Signal Processing (DSP) technology, including compression and echo cancellation
Easily pairs with compatible devices
Bluetooth: v2.0
Talk Time: 15 hours
Standby Time: 25 days
Operating Range: 33 ft. (10 meters)
Size: 3.59� (H) x 1.98� (W) x 0.52� (D)
Weight: 2.11 oz.
Warranty: ANYCOM limited worldwide 2-year warranty

Comment: Where is your code? What you'll need to do is either skip over characters that don't fit into the valid range, or catch the exception.

Comment: the page has text encoded in iso-8859-1 but the meta header says that is utf8, that makes browser to be unable to identify that characters, if you change the encoding to iso-8859-1 will be able to convert to unicode that character

Answer (score 0):

The code is unclear but I think issue is with decoding, It should work after decoding to utf-8

For example,

```
string = '(10 meters) Size: 3.59� (H) x 1.98� (W) x 0.52� (D) Weight:'.decode('utf-8')
```